# uib-datepicker-popup not updating textbox when year 0000 is entered in texbox

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

when manually typing date if year 0000 is entered model value gets updated with year 1 (i.e 0001) but text box still shows year as 0000 where as calendar popup shows 0001 year. I don't know if it is bug, but from user point of view text box should also get updated in case of two way binding.
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/juq5j9HI3rzPI22bis4H?p=preview)

```
enter code here
```

Enter year as 0000, see model value updating but text box does not update

Comment: this is a bug, have you tried letting the developers know? they have an issue tracker

Comment: No, I have not reported it.